# Error "The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'" while reading a Firestore collection

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to get data from firebaseFirestore, but it shows error below, also this article didn't help https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#typing-collectionreference-and-documentreference.

**Code**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:greatr/models/ChatRoom.dart';

FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

    Future getChatRooms() async {
      List<ChatRoom> rooms = [];
      QuerySnapshot response = await firestore.collection('chat_rooms').get();
      response.docs.forEach((element) {
        rooms.add(ChatRoom.fromJson(element.data()!));
      });
     
    }
```

**Error**

```
The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't share the code of the `ChatRoom` class, but I make the assumption it is similar to the example with the `Movie` class in the [documentation you refer to](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#typing-collectionreference-and-documentreference) in your question.

If this assumption is correct, the following should do the trick:

```
final chatRoomsRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chat_rooms').withConverter<ChatRoom>(
      fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => ChatRoom.fromJson(snapshot.data()!),
      toFirestore: (chat_room, _) => chat_room.toJson(),
    );

//...


Future getChatRooms() async {

  List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<ChatRoom>> chat_rooms = await chatRoomsRef
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => snapshot.docs);     
   //...

}
```